# Is it possible to manipulate the index parameter of Array.prototype.map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if it is possible to do a "index--" after deleting an element in an Array while using the map function.

example:

```
arr.map((item, index) => item >= a && item <= b? item : arr.splice(index, 1));
```

after deleting the element at the said index, the index needs to be "index - 1" for the next iteration.
is it possible to somehow manipulate the index in the map function?

Comment: You really should use `filter` instead of `map` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any elegant way. The better option would be to avoid `splice` entirely, and instead use the new returned array from the an array method only, discarding the old one.

If you want to remove items between `a` and `b`, use `.filter`:

```
const itemsNotBetweenAAndB = arr.map(item => item >= a || item <= b);
```

If you *had* to use splice to mutate the existing array (which I'd recommend against since it's ugly and impure), use a `for` loop:

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (arr[i] > a && arr[i] < b) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

`.map` should be used only for creating a new array based on transforming *all elements* of the original array. Since here, it looks like you want to *remove* elements from the original array without transforming each item, `.map` isn't appropriate, since it won't help you accomplish the goal.

Comment: Yeah i know that but for this particular task it was intended to not use a new array. The result should be "in-place" in the same array without use of a new array. basically delete the elements that dont match the condition which leaves an array with only the elements that meet the criteria.
Edit: so its not possible to tackle the task with the map function thats unfortunate. because i thought that i couldve avoided the longer for-loop. thank you for the answer tho!